# Magento2: Notice: Undefined variable: _product

Tags: magento2

I use product slider from mageplaza.

Above product name I try display brand name from attribute: `newbrand_name`

to file `productslider.phtml` I add below code:

```
<?php
$optionText = '';
$attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('newbrand_name');
if ($attr->usesSource()) {
    $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getNewbrandName());
}
?>
<?php if ($optionText) { ?>
    <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div><br />
<?php } ?>
```

In frontend I get issue:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _product in /home/shop/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/Productslider/view/frontend/templates/productslider.phtml on line 50
```

Here is full file code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Productslider
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

use Mageplaza\Productslider\Block\AbstractSlider;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

/** @var AbstractSlider $block */
$mode = 'grid';
$title = $block->getTitle();
$blockId = $block->getSliderId() . uniqid('-', false);
$items = $block->getProductCollection();
if ($items && $items->getSize()) : ?>
    <div class="mp-product-slider-block block widget block-products-list <?= /** @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
        <h2 class="mp-product-slider-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml($title) ?></h2>
        <p class="mp-ps-info"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDescription()) ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content mp-product-slider-content">
        <div class="products-<?= /** @noEscape */  $mode ?> <?= /** @noEscape */  $mode ?>">
            <ol class="product-items widget-viewed-grid">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <div id="mp-list-items-<?= /** @noEscape */ $blockId ?>" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
                        <?= ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item product-slider"">' : '</li><li class="product-item product-slider"">' ?>
                        <div class="slider-product-item-info">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                               class="product photo slider-product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, 'recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget')->toHtml(); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product details slider-product-item-details">
                            <?php 
                                        $optionText = '';
                                        $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('newbrand_name');
                                        if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                                           $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getNewbrandName());
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                                        <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div><br />
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCustomName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCustomName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>

                                <?php if ($block->canShowReview()) : ?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short', true) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($block->canShowPrice()) : ?>
                                    <?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <div class="product actions slider-product-item-actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($block->canShowAddToCart()) : ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                                <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_item); ?>
                                                <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                                    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                    <button type="submit"
                                                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                            class="action tocart primary">
                                                        <span><?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </form>
                                            <?php else : ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else : ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary"
                                             data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                                <a href="#"
                                                   data-post='<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item); ?>'
                                                   class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                   title="<?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Wish List') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl()) : ?>
                                                <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare'); ?>
                                                <a href="#" class="action tocompare"
                                                   data-post='<?= /** @noEscape */ $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item); ?>'
                                                   data-role="add-to-links"
                                                   title="<?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Compare') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?= ($iterator === count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'mageplaza/core/owl.carousel'], function ($) {
            $('#mp-list-items-<?= /** @noEscape */ $blockId ?>').owlCarousel(<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getAllOptions()?>);
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update code in your below file

> app/code/Mageplaza/Productslider/view/frontend/templates/productslider.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Mageplaza
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Mageplaza.com license that is
 * available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade this extension to newer
 * version in the future.
 *
 * @category    Mageplaza
 * @package     Mageplaza_Productslider
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) Mageplaza (https://www.mageplaza.com/)
 * @license     https://www.mageplaza.com/LICENSE.txt
 */

use Mageplaza\Productslider\Block\AbstractSlider;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

/** @var AbstractSlider $block */
$mode = 'grid';
$title = $block->getTitle();
$blockId = $block->getSliderId() . uniqid('-', false);
$items = $block->getProductCollection();
if ($items && $items->getSize()) : ?>
    <div class="mp-product-slider-block block widget block-products-list <?= /** @noEscape */ $mode ?>">
        <h2 class="mp-product-slider-title"><?= $block->escapeHtml($title) ?></h2>
        <p class="mp-ps-info"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getDescription()) ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content mp-product-slider-content">
        <div class="products-<?= /** @noEscape */  $mode ?> <?= /** @noEscape */  $mode ?>">
            <ol class="product-items widget-viewed-grid">
                <?php $iterator = 1; ?>
                <div id="mp-list-items-<?= /** @noEscape */ $blockId ?>" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item) : ?>
                        <?= ($iterator++ == 1) ? '<li class="product-item product-slider"">' : '</li><li class="product-item product-slider"">' ?>
                        <div class="slider-product-item-info">
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                               class="product photo slider-product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, 'recently_viewed_products_grid_content_widget')->toHtml(); ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product details slider-product-item-details">
                            <?php 
                                        $optionText = '';
                                        $attr = $_item->getResource()->getAttribute('newbrand_name');
                                        if ($attr->usesSource()) {
                                           $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_item->getNewbrandName());
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <?php if($optionText){ ?>
                                        <div class="brand-name"><?php echo $optionText ?></div><br />
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                    <a title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCustomName()) ?>"
                                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getCustomName()) ?>
                                    </a>
                                </strong>

                                <?php if ($block->canShowReview()) : ?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, 'short', true) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($block->canShowPrice()) : ?>
                                    <?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <div class="product actions slider-product-item-actions product-item-actions">
                                    <?php if ($block->canShowAddToCart()) : ?>
                                        <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                                                <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_item); ?>
                                                <form data-role="tocart-form" data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>" action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $postParams['action'] ?>" method="post">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data']['product'] ?>">
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED ?>" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED] ?>">
                                                    <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                    <button type="submit"
                                                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                            class="action tocart primary">
                                                        <span><?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                </form>
                                            <?php else : ?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()) : ?>
                                                    <div class="stock available"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                <?php else : ?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary"
                                             data-role="add-to-links">
                                            <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                                <a href="#"
                                                   data-post='<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getAddToWishlistParams($_item); ?>'
                                                   class="action towishlist" data-action="add-to-wishlist"
                                                   title="<?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Wish List') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Wish List') ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php if ($block->getAddToCompareUrl()) : ?>
                                                <?php $compareHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare'); ?>
                                                <a href="#" class="action tocompare"
                                                   data-post='<?= /** @noEscape */ $compareHelper->getPostDataParams($_item); ?>'
                                                   data-role="add-to-links"
                                                   title="<?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Compare') ?>">
                                                    <span><?= /** @noEscape */ __('Add to Compare') ?></span>
                                                </a>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?= ($iterator === count($items) + 1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </div>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
    </div>
    <script>
        require(['jquery', 'mageplaza/core/owl.carousel'], function ($) {
            $('#mp-list-items-<?= /** @noEscape */ $blockId ?>').owlCarousel(<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getAllOptions()?>);
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope this will help you!